# Is there a Powershell remoting equivalent of using psexec as the system account?

Tags: powershell

PSEXEC has a `-s` argument that will "Run the remote process in the System account."

I'm currently using a Powershell remoting session as follows:

```
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $server
```

The user executing this code has admin rights on the target server.

Is there a way to create a PSSession that executes on the target server as the system account in the same way as PSEXEC?

Comment: Why would you want to run as system? That's the highest privileged user on the system. What task needs more permissions than an administrative account?

Comment: It's been suggested to me as a workaround for the bug in KB2918614 which is fixed in KB3000988 without being able to install KB3000988.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to run Powershell remote sessions as system user.

Comment: @Iain, those KB numbers mean nothing to me, so to motivate your request, could you summarize what the problem is?

Comment: @megamorf In order to emulate the context the [SCCM client installs](https://serverfault.com/a/708900/115232) and [detects applications](https://serverfault.com/questions/699705/in-what-context-do-sccm-powershell-detection-scripts-run-in), you need to run in the system context.  If you're doing any amount of automation in that world (eg. automated integration testing) you're going to want to run powershell remotely on the test target as the system account.